# Changing VGA cable on Debian lowers resolution

Tags: linux, debian, graphics-card, resolution, vga

I just changed my VGA cable and Debian says my maximum resolution (in display) can only go upto 1024x768.

I have a 32inch LED monitor that supports a maximum of 1920x1440 (aka the maximum that VGA can support). However when I plug in my old cable, I get this maximum resolution.

I thought it was an issue with the cheap $1 cable so bought a high end one but still the same problem. Now when I use Windows with this new cable—the high end one—I do get the maximum resolution but Debian still refuses to go beyond 1024x768 (the X window manager is Gnome 3 if that helps).

I have dual boot by the way and in windows this new VGA cable works like a charm.

Here are the details of the apparent technical differences (or so it seems) between the cables:

Old one: `HOTRON E246588 RU(looks like an interverted R adjoined with a U) AWM style 20276 vw-1 80C 30V CRU AWM I/II A/B 80C 30V FT1`

New one: `AWM 2919 VW-1 80c 30V VW-1 LOW VOLTAGE COMPUTER CABLE BAILIHENG BLH:20000229`

The only technical thing I could make out from above is the older one is an AWM style 20276 cable whereas the newer one is a AWM style 2919 one.

Could anyone point me somewhere?

Comment: I am not really sure why is it happening as the same cable works fine with Windows 7 whereas it fails to do so in Debian. 

Anyways, if it helps, here are what the cable says

Old one: HOTRON E246588 `RU`(looks like an interverted R adjoined with a U) AWM style 20276 vw-1 80C 30V C`RU` AWM I/II A/B 80C 30V FT1

New one: AWM 2919 VW-1 80c 30V VW-1 LOW VOLTAGE COMPUTER CABLE BAILIHENG BLH:20000229

The only technical thing I could make out from above is the older one is an AWM style 20276 cable whereas the newer one is a AWM style 2919 one. How does that matter?

Comment: Well..Added it to the question above. Thanks for the heads up. Any how, could you make something out of these new details I posted?

Answer (score 1):

How displays work: the monitor is sending the EDID information to the PC. This is how the PC identifies what resolutions are available to the specific monitor.
The VGA cable is allowing this information to be sent from the monitor back to the PC.
The PC then stores temporary this information.  Once the system is shutdown, the EDID information is cleared. This could be a cause. It applies specially if the new cable is longer than the previous one.
Over this, drivers are also involved, so that may also be an issue.

If time allows it, try to run an independent graphical application with resolution manually set to one supported by your display (old Unreal Tournament should run fine on Debian).

A quicker way though, is to manually add a supported resolution.

```
xrandr --addmode VGA1 "1920x1440"
```

Note that VGA1 may already be occupied, so check first and add another number if in use.

Also, if you use two monitors, the problem is that the driver/software detecting the capabilities of lowest of them.

Comment: Sorry for the late comment as I was busy and switched back to my older loose cable. Nevertheless would like to know if using xrandr can cause any permanent damage to my LED monitor? If for instance I experiment with various switches and options?

Comment: Usually, todays monitors will just say 'out of range' and not display anything if the parameters are incorrect/unsupported. They just have a digital access list with all supported mode, everything else is denied, so there should be no problems.

Comment: Hmmmm. Ok. I am  still a little jittery with going ahead. Ill see how far my old cable will take me. When the monitor gets a bit cranky and old, Ill try what has been suggested. Thanks again!